# Not getting response in Ios device check api in for JWT with ES256 Algorithm in php

Tags: php, ios, jwt, devicecheck

I am working with JWT token with algorithm ES256 using PHP to check devices for IOS And successfully create JWT (JSON web token) for it.

I have tried to call API for device check through the  postman
API: https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com/v1/query_two_bits

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Ecdsa\Sha256;

$signer = new Sha256();

$privateKey = new Key('file:///AuthKey_*****.p8');
$time = time();

$token = (new Builder())->issuedBy('**********') 
                        ->issuedAt($time)
                        ->setHeader('kid', '*********')
                        ->getToken($signer,  $privateKey);
```

I have successfully created a JWT token from the above code,

API: https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com/v1/query_two_bits

But when I pass this token in authorization bearer in above API I am getting below error.

**Unable to verify authorization token**

Is there any error while creating an authentication file?

Comment: Where is the code to check the JWT token?

Comment: @JayPandya I have check directly in jwt.io
And it shows Invalid Signature.

Comment: So where do you provide your private key to verify the valid token on jwt.io?

Comment: @JayPandya No, right now I am not providing any private key to verify the valid token in JWT.
Where can I use the private key in jwt.io,


Right now while generating token I use .p8 file to get the private key.
Is that right to get the private key from .p8 file?

Comment: I don't think they are providing any option to verify the `JWT Token` with a private key. So you have to do it in your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks,
For verifying the JWT Token in the code I need to the public key,
Can you please help me, how can I genrate public key?